# Compute/estimate the number of non-isomorphic graphs with $n$ nodes, $a$ edges, $b$ connected components

Tags: co.combinatorics

Given $n$ nodes, denote $^nK^a_b$ as the number of all possible ways of connecting $a$ edges (regardless isomorphism), such that there are $b$ connected components in the graph.

I.e. The number of non-isomorphic graphs with $n$ nodes, $a$ edges, $b$ connected components.

My question is:

Is there general formula or bounds for $^nK^a_b$?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the wording.  Do you mean the number of isomorphism types of graphs with $n$ vertices, $a$ edges, and $b$ connected components?

Comment: Shouldn't it be ${}^nK^a_b$?

Comment: @LSpice yes! Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes thanks, I just modified.

Comment: You modified it in one place, but not in the other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks! I modified both

Comment: Counting graphs by edges and connected components is https://oeis.org/A201922. It should be straightforward to modify this to include the number of edges.

Answer (score 4):

Just a comment, but too long for the comment section:

Let $f(n,a,b)$ be the number of *labelled* graphs on $n$ vertices with
$a$ edges and $b$ connected components. By e.g. Chapter 5 of
*Enumerative Combinatorics*, Vol. 2 (in particular, Example 5.2.2), we
have $$ \sum_{n,a,b}
f(n,a,b)q^a t^b \frac{x^n}{n!} = \left( \sum_{m\geq 0}(1+q)^{{m\choose
2}} \frac{x^m}{m!}\right)^t. $$ To get graphs up to isomorphism, some
argument using Burnside's lemma or Pólya-Redfield theory will be
needed. (This may already be known.) The formula is likely to be
complicated, since even the formula for the total number of graphs, up
to isomorphism, with $n$ vertices is not so simple. Most likely, for
suitable restrictions on $a,b$, the function $^nK_b^a$ will be asymptotic to $f(n,a,b)/n!$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to make the problem simpler such that we can have explicit bounds, by assuming an underlying graph structure? Meaning that, the connected edges can only be the edges in the underlying graph.